# How to convert nanoseconds to milliseconds

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, milliseconds

I'm trying to get `milliseconds` from `NSCalendarUnit`. I was able to get `nanosecond`, but that has way too many numbers. All I want is 2 numbers. Here is my code:

```
var startDate = NSDate()
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)

let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", dateComponents.nanosecond)
timeLabel.text = "\(strFraction)"
```

How can I get milliseconds from the NSCalendarUnit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is no `Calendar.Component.millisecond`, as opposed to [`Calendar.Component.nanosecond`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/component/nanosecond), we would need to convert from nanoseconds to milliseconds. 1 millisecond is 1000000 nanoseconds, so you would need to divide the number of nanoseconds by 1000000. If you want an integer value, `round(nanoseconds/1000000)`

Comment: I tried the following: `let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", round(dateComponents.nanosecond/1000000))`
And it gave me the following error: `Cannot find an overload for 'round' that accepts an argument list of type'(Int)'`

Comment: That is because `round` cannot handle a regular integer for a argument.  It only accepts a double or a float. So, you want to cast `dateComponents.nanosecond/1000000` to a double by `Double(dateComponents.nanosecond)/1000000`

Comment: Do you mean the following: 
`let millisecond : Double = (dateComponents.nanosecond)/1000000`